# Unable to display a simple image in Phaser

Tags: javascript, html, game-development, phaser-framework

So I wanted to use Phaser for a project I'm trying to make. I was following the tutorial on their website, but then I hit a bare wall. In one of the lines I wrote, it said this:

```
function create() {
  this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');
}
```

I read the article, and it is supposed to display a picture of a sky (which I imported into my project beforehand), but it is still a blank screen.

I tried a lot of things so far but it is still not working. Can someone help?

Here's all the relevant config:

```
var config = {
 type: Phaser.AUTO,
 width: 800,
 height: 600,
 scene: {
 preload: preload,
 create: create,
 update: update,
 },
};
```

And Code:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

//Loads in sprites
function preload() {
  this.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png');
  this.load.image('ground', 'assets/platform.png');
  this.load.image('star', 'assets/star.png');
  this.load.image('bomb', 'assets/bomb.png');
  this.load.spritesheet('dude', 'assets/dude.png', {
    frameWidth: 32,
    frameHeight: 48,
  });
}

//Displays sprites
function create() {
  this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');
}

//Update loop
function update() {}
```

Comment: I have a feeling you are not sharing all the relevant code. I'm going to take a guess... You have no loaded the images and therefore see nothing.

Comment: I have in fact loaded the images. Like stated, there is nothing on the screen

Comment: Show all the relevant code. When I say load I don't mean imported like you stated.

Comment: yes i know that, also now all the code is in post

Comment: Maybe you need to call `this.load.setBaseURL(` in your preload function before all the calls to load the images.

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser

Comment: I feel like it's just not finding the images and it's displaying a blank canvas.

Comment: @tazer900 to beable to answer this question, I have some questions. :) Are you runing the project on a webserver? Are there any errors in the Browser Console?

Comment: @winner_joiner im using playcode.io for coding. they have a preview website to see my project

Comment: Please come up with a good question title.

Answer (score 2):

Check the **urls** of the assets, in your code, with the project **folder structure** on [playcode.io](https://playcode.io).
Tried to run the code on playcode and it seems to works:
*(atleast **when you publish** the website. The webpreview freezes/crashes, I have to assume, that this is a issue of [codeplay.io](https://codeplay.io) in conjunction with with the phaser framework)*

**Editor:**
[image: screenshot playcode.io]

**Result:**
[image: screenshot result browser]

[link to the working demo](https://978093.playcode.io/)

**Update *(if you need the preview)*:**

Since it seems that the preview on [playcode.io](https://playcode.io) uses temp files and the Urls don't really match the real file - structure, you could use this workaround, to side step this issue.
Just:

1. For any image, that you want to load in phaser, load it image simply in html.
   example: `<img id="sky" src="assets/sky.png" style="width:1px;height:1px;" />`
2. And in the phaser `preload` function replace all `this.load.image` with `this.textures.addImage`
   Here a [link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Textures.TextureManager.html#addImage__anchor)

**Here a example:**

Replace the line of code:

```
this.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png');
```

with this one:

```
this.textures.addImage('sky', document.getElementById('sky'));
```

> Since it **seems**, that playcode preview cannot handle generating *images-urls* from javascript, you could use this workaround. **BUT** only for development on playcode, for production, or when you publish use the original `this.load.image(...)`. *the workaround works also on production, but is not optimal and not recommended.*